# stringtotime beginning and end of the month not working proppely

Tags: php, date

I have the code:

```
$month = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/Y', $date);

if ($month) {
    $month = $month -> format('01/m/Y');
}

echo "From ".$startMonth." to ".$endMonth = date("t/m/Y", strtotime($month));
```

when `$date` is a string like "05/2015".

This returns:

> From 01/05/2015 to 31/01/2015

But for some reason the month is coming up as `01` when it should be `05`?
Why is it doing this? It should be

> From 01/05/2015 to 31/05/2015

Comment: you should have used `DateTime` all thru out

Comment: try with php data function <?php echo $today = date('d/m/Y');?>

Comment: Besides the unnecessary chopping and changing between DateTime objects and unix timestamps (when you could do the whole thing using DateTime objects.... you're passing a formatted date of `'01/m/Y'` to `strtotime()`... the `/` indicates US date format (`mm/dd/yy`) and you should use `'01-m-Y'` (with a `-`) for `dd-mm-YYYY` for European dates

Comment: Also, it's bad practice to keep reusing the same variable over and over

Answer (score 1):

Besides the unnecessary chopping and changing between DateTime objects and unix timestamps (when you could do the whole thing using DateTime objects.... you're passing a formatted date of `'01/m/Y'` to `strtotime()`... the `/` indicates to the `strtotime()` function that the date is in **US** date format (`mm/dd/yy`): and you should use `'01-m-Y'` (with a `-`) for `dd-mm-YYYY` if you want to tell `strtotime()` that it's a **European** format date.

See the "localized notations" table on the [PHP Docs page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) for an explanation of formats accepted by `strtotime()`

However, doing the whole thing using DateTime objects:

```
$date = '4/2015';
$month = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/Y', $date);
echo "From " . $month->format('01/m/Y') . " to ". $month->format('t/m/Y');
```